# Standards for a database design document

Tags: database, documentation, standards

I am beginning the process of putting together a design document for my companies database.  I am trying to use as many formal standards as I can.  Does anyone know "Is there a standards document (like IEEE 1016 1998 IEEE Recommended Practice for Software Design Descriptions) for databases"?  WIKI talks about a Database Design Document, but I can't seem to find any "good" examples of what a database design document should include.

There are a few other questions on Stack Overflow that are close to this, but not exactly what I am after.  I have been poking around on the web and cannot find a good answer to the question either.  Does anyone know of such a standard or would I be better off just adapting IEEE 1016 1998 to meet my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grappled with this same problem a couple years ago. I resorted to using Joe Celko's excellent book `SQL Programming Style` to help me put together our company's database standards document.

```
http://www.amazon.com/Celkos-Programming-Kaufmann-Management-Systems/dp/0120887975/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1289941772&sr=1-7
```

Comment: Really?  I leafed through that book and was really turned off by the SHOUT-CASE SQL and the not-so-source-control-diffing-friendly formatting.  Of course, if you need to go with what someone else printed in order to lend some validity to your coding style, be my guest.  But don't pretend it isn't just some guys' opinions.

Comment: @mattmc3 - The question wasn't about coding style, it was about standards. I think you need to take a closer look at the book. Celko covers standards in depth in chapter 1 where he discusses SQL-92 standards, ISO-11179 standards, NCITS L8 Metadata Standards rules, ISO-3166 standards and more. He covers more standards, in depth, in chapter 3, related to the SQL language.

Comment: The best part about putting together a standards document based on a book is to go "look at what we've learned since then" and "this is our internal structure, modeled off his goals but tailored to our organization". :D